# Is there a way to delete 0's from a dataset?

Tags: sas

Suppose I want to only apply proc means or the better means macro to only non zero entries in my dataset? Is there an easy option to do this? If I have a dataset:

```
A B C 
0 1 2
2 2 0
2 0 1
```

How can I use proc means or the better means macro to ignore the 0 values?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a view to convert them on the fly.  BETTERMEANS may have a way of handling this; not sure.

```
data have;
input A B C ;
format a b c zeromissing1.;
datalines;
0 1 2
2 2 0
2 0 1
;;;;
run;

data have_z/view=have_z;
set have;
array num _numeric_;
do _i = 1 to dim(num);
  if num[_i]=0 then num[_i]=.;
end;
run;

proc means data=have_z;
var a b c;
run;
```